# IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch in Java

Tags: java, observer-pattern

I created this code for notify the observers of my program. But when I call notfyObservers() method, it gives me the error. This is Java RMI Program.

> IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch in Java

notifyObserver() Method:

```
@Override
public void notifyObservers(JPanel ob) throws RemoteException {
    Object[] arrLocal;

    synchronized (this) {
        if (!changed) {
            return;
        }
        arrLocal = listObs.toArray();
        clearChanged();
    }
    for (int i = arrLocal.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        ((RemoteObserver) arrLocal[i]).modify(this, ob);
    }
}
```

Called as..

```
questionController.notifyObservers(null);
```

I call this method in a `JPanel`, And my Error is when I passed the jpanel..

```
java.rmi.MarshalException: error marshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.io.NotSerializableException: javax.swing.GroupLayout
```

If i passed null, I got.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: The stacktrace will give you the line of the error.

Answer (score 0):

It seams `JPanel` argument could not be null in `modify()` method

```
((RemoteObserver) arrLocal[i]).modify(this, ob)
```

**UPD** Wow, you are trying to send `JPanel` with some not `Serializable` components through web service. probably you should just send some parameters instead.

Comment: GroupLayout is not a serialized, I think